A consequence of kernels of linear functionals being maximal: functionals of norm $1$ from general bounded operators?
I came upon the following exercise, and since it's been a while since I've done any analysis, I'd like to have my attempt checked. Thanks!

Let $K \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$. Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T: X \to Y$ be a continuous linear map, such that $\|T\| > 0$. Show that there exists a continuous linear functional $f: X \to K$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $\ker T \subseteq \ker f$.

My attempt is as follows:

Because $\operatorname{codim}( \ker f ) = 1$, it is maximal amongst proper subspaces of $X$. As $\|T\| > 0$, the given linear map $T$ is non-zero, and hence $\ker T$ is a proper subspace of $X$. Thus, there is an inclusion $\ker T \subseteq \ker f$ automatically, so any linear functional $f: X \to K$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ suffices; note that such functionals are bounded, hence continuous.

Why I'm unsure:

It seems to be that we do not need $X, Y$ to be complete at all, only that they are normed.
Would the result still hold if $T$ was an unbounded operator ? I ended up not using the continuity assumption at all.

Otherwise, please let me know of any mistake!
Corrections to attempted solution:   In conclusion, we don't need $X, Y$ to be complete, but $T$ being continuous is essential: otherwise, $\ker T$ can be dense (e.g. when $Y = K$, in which case $\operatorname{codim}(\ker T) = 1$), and in that case $\ker T \subseteq \ker f$ if and only if $\ker f$ is dense too, which is only the case either when $f$ is discontinuous or zero, both can not occur when $\|f\| = 1$.

What is $f$ ? You haven't defined it.

@ryszardszwarc Can't I just take any $f \in X^*$ with norm $1$, since it is not required that the inclusion $\ker T \subseteq \ker f$ is strict (which I believe covers the cases wherein $T$ is unbounded too, per the last part of your answer below) ? Thanks for taking the time to answer, btw!

Not every continuous functional satisfies $\ker T\subset \ker f.$ Moreover if $\ker T$ is dense then there is no  nonzero bounded functional such that $\ker T\subset \ker f.$  See my answer.

@RyszardSzwarc ah I see my mistake now. Thanks! I'll accept your answer.

As $T\neq 0,$ there exists $x_0$ so that $Tx_0\neq 0.$ Thus there is a bounded linear functional $g:Y\to K$ such that $g(Tx_0)=1.$ Let $h=g\circ T.$ Then $h$ is a bounded linear functional on $X.$ Moreover $\ker T\subset \ker h.$ We have $h(x_0)=g(Tx_0)=1,$ Hence $h\neq 0.$ The functional $f=\|h\|^{-1}h$ satisfies the requirements.
The completness of $X$ and $Y$ is not essential. However the continuity of $T$ is essential. For example if $Y=K$ and $T$ is not continuous, then $\ker T$ is dense in $X.$ The inclusion $\ker T\subset \ker f,$ where $f$ is continuous, would imply $\ker f=X,$ i.e. $f=0.$
